# Разница во времени на Java

Tags: java, время, временная-зона

Как задать 2 даты и посмотреть сколько времени между ними прошло.

Например:

```
01.01.2000 10:10:10
02.03.2005 20:10:20
```

и получить в ответ: `1 день 2 месяца 5 лет 10 часов 0 минут 10 секунд`

И потом понадобится сортировка от самого большого времени к самому маленькому.
Пишу на Java 7.

Answer (score 12):

Это легко сделать с помощью [org.joda.time.Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html)

```
private static String strDiff(DateTime from, DateTime to) {
    Period period = new Period(from, to, PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime());
    return 
      period.getYears() + "y " +
      period.getMonths() + "m " + 
      period.getDays() + "d " + 
      period.getHours() + "h " + 
      period.getMinutes() + "min " + 
      period.getSeconds() + "s" + 
      "";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    DateTime start = formatter.parseDateTime("2017-04-03 03:00:00");
    DateTime end   = formatter.parseDateTime("2017-04-11 03:00:00");

    System.out.println(strDiff(start, end));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Создайте два Date, потом возьмите из них время в миллисекундах и узнаете разницу. Затем парсите.

Comment: Почему минусуют то? Ответ верный ведь...

Comment: @Barmaley, Не минусовал, но и ответ неверный. Одинаковое количество миллисекунд в разное время может означать разные периоды. Особенно неоднозначна задача распарсить количество месяцев...